# Leaving Colombia

Tags: passports, us-citizens, dual-nationality, colombia, colombian-citizens

I was born in Colombia, and also an American citizen. I have dual citizenship and understand that I need to show the Colombian passport to enter Colombia. But what about upon departure? Which passport do I show to leave the country?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on who wants to see it.

To the airline you show the passport that gives you entry at the destination, so the US passport. To be safe, show them both.

If there is exit immigration, you show them the same passport you used to entere the country.

Comment: The airlines makes sense as my name matches the American passport. For immigration purposes, if I show them my colombian passport won’t they be inclined to ask about a visa. Or is that when I show them my american passport?